# Flag consecutive occurrences of value in column based on conditional from other column

Tags: r

Details of the problem: I've created a toy example. Each person has a time-series response vector that indicates whether a subject is sleeping, eating, or walking throughout a time-series. For the purpose of this example, all consecutive occurrences of "eat" that occur immediately after "sleep" are significant. I have a scenario where I have created a counter variable that tallies the consecutive occurrence of the same responses in a vector. However, I only care to keep or flag those consecutive counts of "eat" that occur after sleep.

In the code below: I created a lag-1 variable to then create a flag for each instance of "eat" that follows sleep. However, this only flags the start of each instance of "eat", and I want to flag all occurrences of "eat" that follow a "sleep" so that I can create summary statistics based on the counter variable in the code below.

I'm stuck on how to get through this problem.

Code is below:

```
# load libraries
packs <- c('data.table', 'dplyr')
lapply(packs, require, character.only = TRUE)

# 1. initiate data
df <- data.frame(
    id = c(rep(101, 6), rep(102, 8)),
    response = c('sleep', 'sleep', 'sleep', 'eat', 'eat', 'walk', 'walk', 'sleep', 'sleep', 'eat', 'eat', 'walk', 'eat', 'walk'))

# 2. create the lag-1 variable and flag for that start of all occurrences of 
df <- df %>%
    mutate(lag_response = lag(response, 1),
    flag = case_when(lag_response == 'sleep' & response == "eat" ~ 1)) %>%
    select(id, lag_response, response, flag)

# 3. create consecutive counter for responses 
df <- transform(df, counter = ave(c(response), rleid(id, c(response)), FUN = seq_along))

# 4. example of desired column 
df <- df %>%
    mutate(
    desired_col = c(0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can create the 'flag' by comparing the 'response' values that are "sleep" and the next value as "eat" using `lead`, grouped by `rleid` of 'response', `mutate` 'flag' by changing with `any` TRUE

```
library(dplyr)
library(data.table)
df %>% 
   mutate(flag = lag(response == 'sleep' & lead(response) == 'eat', 
                     default = FALSE))  %>% 
   group_by(grp = rleid(response)) %>% 
   mutate(flag = +any(flag)) %>% 
   ungroup %>%
   select(-grp)
```

Answer (score 3):

In *base* you can use `ave`. To get the flip from `sleep` to `eat` you simple compare with shifted indices. To propagate the hit to all following `eats` you use `diff` and `cumsum` to define groups.

```
df$f <- ave(c(FALSE, df$response[-nrow(df)] == "sleep" & df$response[-1] == "eat")
  , cumsum(c(FALSE, diff(unclass(df$response)) != 0))
  , FUN=function(x) x[1])
df
#    id response     f
#1  101    sleep FALSE
#2  101    sleep FALSE
#3  101    sleep FALSE
#4  101      eat  TRUE
#5  101      eat  TRUE
#6  101     walk FALSE
#7  102     walk FALSE
#8  102    sleep FALSE
#9  102    sleep FALSE
#10 102      eat  TRUE
#11 102      eat  TRUE
#12 102     walk FALSE
#13 102      eat FALSE
#14 102     walk FALSE
```